# How normalize url in nextjs (firebase-based)

Tags: firebase, express, next.js

I'm trying to make a middleware for normalize urls (I want to sort get-params and remove extra '&'-symbols) and got some problem when tried to deploy it to firebase hosting

I want to fix urls like this `https://lol.kek/?b=1&z=2&a=3&&&` -> `https://lol.kek/?a=3&b=1&z=2`

For this I made a middleware

```
# /src/pages/_app.ts

const middleware: NextMiddleware = (req: NextRequest, event: NextFetchEvent) => {
  const finalResponse = NextResponse.next();
  const { origin, pathname, search } = new URL(req.url);
  
  // this is my experiments how to get non-normalized url
  const originUrl = `${origin}${req.headers.get('x-original-url') || (pathname + search)}`;
  const url = normalizeUrl(originUrl.toString());

  if (isDev) {
    console.log(`normalizeUrlMiddleware req.url:${req.url} from:${origin}${req.headers.get('x-original-url')}; to:${url}`);
    res?.headers.set('X-HAVE-TO-REDIRECT', `from:${origin}${req.headers.get('x-original-url')}; to:${url}`);
  }

  if (originUrl !== url) {
    return NextResponse.redirect(url, req);
  }

  return finalResponse;
};

...

EnhancedApp.middleware = middleware;
```

It looks and work well on local server `next dev` and `firebase emulators:start`
But when I'm trying to deploy it to firebase, It's stopping to work

Firebase function for use SSR

```
const { https } = require('firebase-functions');
const next = require('next');
const config = require('../next-static-config.js')

const hostname = 'localhost';
const port = 3000;

const baseConfig = {
  dev: false,
  hostname,
  port,
  conf: {
    distDir: '.next',
    ...config
  },
  minimalMode: false
};

const server = next({ ...baseConfig });
const nextjsHandle = server.getRequestHandler();

exports.nextServerDev = https.onRequest((req, res) => nextjsHandle(req, res));
```

Then I try to get some non-normalize url http://lol.kek/?&lang=en&domain=https%3A%2F%2F84fb-81-214-161-57.ngrok-free.app&&&

When I try it local, I see in log correct messages like this
`NormalizeUrlMiddleware req.url:http://localhost:3000/?&lang=ru&domain=https%3A%2F%2F84fb-81-214-161-57.ngrok-free.app&&& to:http://localhost:3000/?domain=https%3A%2F%2F84fb-81-214-161-57.ngrok-free.app&lang=en`
then get correct redirect and everything fine

But on firebase when I try to get the same url I get already normalized urls in log
`NormalizeUrlMiddleware req.url:http://localhost:3000/?domain=https%3A%2F%2F84fb-81-214-161-57.ngrok-free.app&lang=ru to:http://localhost:3000/?domain=https%3A%2F%2F84fb-81-214-161-57.ngrok-free.app&lang=en`
So redirect doesn't happen and I get a page with incorrect address

Has anyone experienced a similar issue when deploying to Firebase Hosting? Are there any known peculiarities of Firebase Hosting that might automatically normalize URL parameters?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: whats your firebaseTool version?

Comment: @RaoAsim `firebase-tools@^12.4.4:
  version "12.4.8"`